# How to execute function after all observableArray dependencies executed in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an observableArray. I want to execute a function after deletion or addition of an item from an observableArray and after completion of all its dependency subscription calls. Like :

```
 observableArray.push(newObject);

 //I can't put my function call at this point because if any subscription is..
 //with newObject or observableArray will execute asynch, and i.. 
 //want my function to execute after all such subscription execution.
```

Is there any way to achieve this in knockout ?

Comment: What kind of thing do you want to do after the update? You can define callbacks in a foreach binding that are fired as array items are changed. http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html - See note 7.  Is this the kind of thing you wanted?

Comment: i want to update a flag which i am also using in the dependencies which executes after observableArray operations (push, pop ..etc), so i want this flag to update only after completing all the dependencies execution for the observable array and the new item which is inserting in array.

Comment: What dependency subscriptions are you talking about? Wouldn't they have already been fired when you created the new object? Can you create a jsFiddle to show what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I thought that events were fired asynchronously, so I wrote the following [Live JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sKUcc/)
:

```
var flagUpdater = ko.observable(0),
    aList = ko.observableArray(["Foo", "Bar", "Baz"]);

flagUpdater.subscribe(function() {
  console.log("Change the flag now!");
});

aList.subscribe(function() {
  console.log("Schedule flag update");
  flagUpdater("blah");
});

aList.push("Qoo");
```

but it doesn't work. It seems that callbacks are all processed synchronously, ie all callbacks already returned once the modifier function (`push()` for example) has returned. So you can simply set the flag after manipulating the array [(live)](http://jsfiddle.net/sKUcc/2/):

```
aList.push("Qoo");
flag = "CHANGED";
console.log("Flag is now " + flag);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but can you please elaborate your suggestion, if it contains an example than it will be great

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `observableArray.push()` will return true, but give this a shot;

```
if (observableArray.push(newObject)) {
    console.log(observableArray);
}
```